# How to encrypt Stripe keys in Wordpress database?

Tags: php, wordpress, security, encryption, stripe-payments

My question is maybe not very limited to Stripe keys but maybe a general problem.
I developed a Stripe payment plugin for WP and gave the web site admin the ability to set her/his API keys (which are a public key and a secret key)  in an option page in the WP dashboard.
So far so good, I used php's `password_hash()` function to encrypt and save the keys in the options table.
Now here's the thing. When users go to website and buy something, how can I decrypt the keys, since I have no salt to compare against.

I can create a salt to store in the database the first time the admin sets her/his keys in the admin dashboard but encrypting and decrypting the salt needs another salt.

So as far as I understand all encryption/decryption algorithms need a salt and it's logical. But in a scenario like this, what's the best way?

The following code is just for you to see what my code looks like even though it has not much to do with the problem I face.

```
 $public_key= password_hash($_POST['pub-key'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
 $secure_key=password_hash($_POST['sec-key'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT) ;

 add_option('pub',$public_key,'','no');
 add_option('sec',$secure_key,'','no');
```

So lets say I want to get my `'pub'` and `'sec'` back from the DB in one of my website pages. Without a salt I can't `password_verify('SALT',get_option('pub');`.

Comment: `password_hash` does not encrypt, but hashes. You cannot revert it.

Comment: @zerkms So what's the best way to do it?

Comment: Just store it as-is? You have not explained what you're protecting it against.

Comment: @zerkms is it a good practice? Since even WP itself stores password as encrypted

Comment: It encrypts user passwords and saves it to the DB. What if my DB get hacked? The keys can be used to access my Stripe API.

Comment: Users' passwords are not encrypted but hashed. Irregardless of how you implement it - if your site/code can decrypt it, then someone who stole everything (db + code) can do as well. Please change your question so it addressed any of your concerns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130919/discussion-between-devman-and-zerkms).

Comment: Can you please chat with me a few minutes?

Answer (score 0):

> So as far as I understand all encryption/decryption algorithms need a salt and it's logical. But in a scenario like this, what's the best way?

No, encryption/decryption needs a *key*, not a salt.

Salting is a distinct thing for password hashing. [Hashing and encryption are totally unrelated concepts](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded#passwords), and password hashing (which is what `password_hash()` does) is its own can of worms.

Encryption is reversible (if you have the key). Hashing is always one-way. Password hashing is slow and salted.

The general problem of secure credential management is, largely, unsolved. However, [some designs are robust against common threat models](https://websec.io/2018/06/14/Keep-Credentials-Secure.html) and might be worth looking into.